# SQL where/or confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running sql statements on a huge db for the first time and I have code as such.

```
Select x, sum(y), sum(z) from db
 where n = 'xxx' or n = 'yyy' and m = int
group by x
```

Now if I do this

```
Select x, sum(y), sum(z) from db
     where n = 'xxx' and m = int
    group by x
Select x, sum(y), sum(z) from db
     where n = 'yyy' and m = int
    group by x
```

And manually add the grouped values together from the 2 tables I am getting different results in my queries, with the separated queries being more accurate.

E.G. Result for row 1 will in the first query will be 20 million, Result for adding Row 1's together in the second block of code will be like 18 million? Not sure what the issue is...?

Comment: I believe you need the top one to read `where (n='xxx' or n='yyy') and m=int`.

Comment: Well that was easy :) Thanks

Comment: You should also check out this syntax: `where n in ('xxx', 'yyy') and ...`

Comment: Your first query should return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to use parentheses when `OR`'s are used with `AND`'s.

```
select x, sum(y), sum(z) from db
where (n = 'xxx' or n = 'yyy') and m = int
group by x
```

In SQL, an `AND` takes precedence over an `OR`.

So this:

```
where n = 'xxx' or n = 'yyy' and m = int
```

Is actually processed as:

```
where n = 'xxx' or (n = 'yyy' and m = int)
```

And that gets the `n` that are 'xxx' with any `m`.

Anyway, Gordon has a point.
Using an `IN` for this is better. Even if it's only 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`.  Your code doesn't really make sense:

```
where n in ('xxx', 'yyy') and m = int
```

This query:

```
where n = 'xxx' or 'yyy' and m = int
```

should return an error in SQL Server, because of the dangling `'yyy'`.  MySQL accepts this syntax.  In that database, it would be processed as:

```
where n = 'xxx' or 'yyy' and m = int

   -- AND has higher precedence than `or`
where n = 'xxx' or ('yyy' and m = int)

   -- `'yyy'` is converted to an integer
where n = 'xxx' or (0 and m = int)

   -- which is treated as a boolean
where n = 'xxx' or (false and m = int)

   -- which is grouped like this
where n = 'xxx' or (false and (m = int))

   -- which is equivalent to
where n = 'xxx'
```